# Why does BuildContext have no mounted property?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to access to 'mounted' property, as [specified in the Flutter docs.](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext/mounted.html)

With the following code...

```
      if (context.mounted) {

      }
```

I get the following error...

> The getter 'mounted' isn't defined for the type 'BuildContext'.
> Try importing the library that defines 'mounted', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'mounted'.

I am on the latest flutter version avaible by running 'upgrade'...

> Flutter 3.3.10 • channel stable •
> https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git Framework • revision 135454af32
> (2 weeks ago) • 2022-12-15 07:36:55 -0800 Engine • revision 3316dd8728
> Tools • Dart 2.18.6 • DevTools 2.15.0

Comment: Your context probably refers to something else. Can you update with a code snippet demonstrating the issue?

Comment: The documentation appears to be wrong - there is no mounted property. You'd only be interested in its value in a stateful widget's state's build, where it is a member.

Answer (score 1):

This was added in flutter 3.7.0. Running `flutter upgrade` worked for me as I was somehow still on flutter 3.3.x.

Answer (score 0):

BuildContext will soon have a mounted property:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/111619

`context.mounted`

Answer (score -1):

the `mounted` bool is an independent variable of the `State`, it's not a member on the `BuildContext`, so instead use:

```
  if (mounted) {

  }
```

Comment: yes, thank you for clarifying it, I will edit

Comment: Incorrect. Read the post and the linked docs. This quesiton does not refer to State class.